# Cost Analysis of Recursive Pascal Triangle Program

Tags: c++, recursion, big-o

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int pascal(int row, int col) 
{
  if (col == 0 || col == row) 
  {
    return 1;
  } 
  else
  {
    return pascal(row - 1, col - 1) + pascal(row - 1, col);
  }
}


int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int row;
    cout<<"Enter n : ";
    cin>>row;

    
    for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int col =0;col<=i;col++)
            cout<<pascal(i,col);

        cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand the cost analysis of the Main Function, but I can't get to understand the Recursive Function cost analysis. How many times does the recursive part pascal(i-1,j-1) + pascal(i-1,j) run?

Comment: Well, you could try adding some debugging logic to see how many times it actually runs for some given `i, j` values (set a global variable to 0 before the top-level call, and have the function add 1 each time it is called, and see how it ends up). See if you can detect a pattern in the result, then see if you can prove it (hint: try using induction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to calculate, but you might want to pay more attention to edge cases, e.g. negative arguments or cases where `row < col`.

Now, without the `col == row` condition (and assuming `col >= 0`), the number of total calls will be the sum of a Pascal’s Triangle, which is roughly `pow(2, col+1) - 1`. This is therefore a simple upper bound on the cost.

At the point where `col == row` (assuming initially `row > col`), your tree is "truncated". To calculate the complexity from this point is an interesting mathematical question that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (though you might want to try [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)).

Note that this code is extremely inefficient - an exponential running time is prohibitively expensive in most cases, and this specific problem can be solved with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) with a significantly lower cost (less than `pow(col, 2)`).